# Add value to line if not yet present

Tags: salt-stack

Having a config file with lines similar to that below:

```
APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS="BLI BLA BLUBB"
```

How do I check if "APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS" already contains the value `SSL` at either start, in the middle, or at the end, and add it if it is not present, such that it becomes:

```
APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS="BLI BLA BLUBB SSL"
```

As one can see, the separator between key (`APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS`) and value (`BLI BLA BLUBB`) is an equal (`=`) sign, and the separator within the value is a space. The value itself is contained within double quotes.

Any smart way to do this except fiddling with regexes?

**UPDATE** It could be that "APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS" does not exist at all and should be added with SSL as sole value.

Comment: IMO this is an opportunity to "ensure" that `APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS` are set to exactly what you want based on grains, environment, pillar data, etc.

Comment: Have you taken a look at file.line: https://archive.repo.saltproject.io/en/2018.3/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.line

Comment: @SourMonk Not sure why you're linking to a doc of Salt 2018. In the meantime file.line is deprecated and file.replace should be used. And yes I've looked at those docs.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are using a configuration management tool, my recommendation would be to use it as such. Rather than doing checks and modifications, which IMHO is a "scripty" way - it would be better to just render the line as we want.

```yaml
ssl-config:
  file.keyvalue:
  - name: /tmp/my-sample.conf
  - key: APACHE_SERVER_FLAGS
  - value: "\"{{ pillar['apache_flags'] }}\""
  - append_if_not_found: True
```

This will ensure that the appropriate flags are rendered according to pillar data for those machines. We can also use grains, or saltenv to define appropriate configuration.